# Issues with Group functions

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, sqlplus

I'm working on lab question that I just cannot come up with a solution, that would allow me to figure out the books that have more then one author(See the posted question below for my comments to make sense). My mind is totally  blank on it. I'm very bad with word problems. I know that I have to do a JOIN statement which I've completed and I know that I have to use the COUNT function to count the number of authors but I honestly don't know how I would go about only counting the books that have 2 authors.

Any input would be appreciated. I tried to break it down into steps but it's just that one part that I'm not grasping in my mind.

4. Using the correct tables in your schema, create a query using either join operation you wish that will list the book title and number of authors for all books that have been written by more than one author. Give the title column an alias of "Book Title" and the column showing the number of authors an alias of "Number of Authors".

There is a BOOKS table and a AUTHOR table that are JOINED by a BOOK_AUTHOR table by their BOOKID in BOOKS and AUTHORID in AUTHOR.

I think I'm starting to understand that I have to use a mathematical equation to figure out more then one author. I don't understand the HAVING function all too well so I'm going to do more research on this one.

Comment: Nobody here is going to do your homework. Show some effort to solve the problem. Alteast add the join query.

Comment: You should have at least posted database schema here.

Comment: I'm not asking for anyone to do my homework at all & I'm not even asking for the answer, I want to be pointed in the right direction & don't have any code to post because I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what it is, exactly that i need to do to narrow it down to only 2 authors. So thanks for your rude comments, they didn't help at all. Please don't bother to post and be arrogant if you have no desire to help. Not all who post to this website are looking to get a pass at their homework. I genuinely am struggling with this question and don't know how to tackle it. @NoDisplayName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, you need a `JOIN`, a `COUNT`, but also an `HAVING` to make sure there is more then one authors that written the book :

```
select title as 'Book Title', count(authors) as 'Number of Authors'
from books
join authors on books.id = authors.book_id
having count(authors) > 1
group by authors;
```

Make sure to adapt the table names and columns to the right one, as you didn't post them.

Note that if the books's author id column has the same name as the author id, you can use the `USING` keyword to join. then your query would become

```
select title as 'Book Title', count(authors) as 'Number of Authors'
from books
join authors on using(book_id)
having count(authors) > 1
group by authors;
```

Note that if you want to select only books that specifically have 2 authors you can change the having clause to `having count(authors) = 2`. But even if you ask for that in your question, according to the exercice you pasted, you did not understand properly the question.

Comment: So what about this `counting the books that have 2 authors`

Comment: @NoDisplayName I think he simply made an error in understanding his homework question, if you look at the question he paste, it specify "*books that have been written by more than one author.*" .

Comment: Nicolle Chase wants books with more than one author and you had join on `books.author_id = authors.id`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard - I think OP posted wrong question his explanation clearly says to do something else

Comment: @JenishRabadiya there is a group by and an having if you did not notice.

Comment: @NoDisplayName I doubt it because, if you read the first sentence it once again specify books having more then one authors and this is not a paste "*I just cannot come up with a solution, that would allow me to figure out the books that have more then one author*"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard `books.author_id = authors.id` means `books` have column called `author_id` then how can it be possible to have multiple author to one book?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Oh, didn't notice that, edited. Would have helped to have the column name at first :) Thanks for the precision.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Now it looks better... :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the answer with all your help. Please see below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title "Book Title", COUNT(*)"Number of Authors"
FROM BOOKS JOIN
BOOK_AUTHOR ON
BOOKS.BookId = BOOK_AUTHOR.BookId
JOIN AUTHOR ON
BOOK_AUTHOR.AuthorId = Author.AuthorId
GROUP BY Title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```